# retrieving specific textview id from listview in onitemclicklistener

Tags: android, textview

I am using this in my code , but if i print the "text" i get "Http response collected as xmldocument parsedchild node no 1child node no 1child node no 1child node no 1child node no 1child node no 11034_HAR"     when i am supposed to get only 11034_HAR . Can someone explain to me why this is happening.

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.siteid);
        String text = textView.getText().toString(); 
        System.out.println(text);                               
        Intent intnt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectedSiteActivity.class);
        startActivity(intnt);
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe you are using wrong ID R.id.siteid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access your `Adapter` using

```
Adapter adapter = arg0.getAdapter();
```

and from the adapter you can access the Item using

```
MyItem item = adapter.getItem(arg2);
```

i suposed MyItem is the entity class you are using with the adapter.

then print the value store in item

```
item.getSiteID();
```

> FYI:
>
> arg2= position
>
> arg3= id

Comment: thanks for the answer , it worked for me . and sorry about the late reply